# How to add plugin to the Visual Studio Cordova project

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

How can I add the remote (git) plugin to the cordova/phonegap project, created with Visual Studio phonegap template?
I can't just change current directory to the VS project in CLI via `cd` and call `add plugin ...`, because it fails with `"project directory could not be found"`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can add plugin through Visual Studio also, following are steps to add custom plugin

1. Download the plugin from GitHub as a .zip file
2. Extract the contents of the .zip file and add them to your project
3. In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for your project, and then choose Add, New Folder. Name the folder plugins
4. Add the code files for your plugin in a subfolder, matching the plugin's folder and file structure
5. Build your app to add the plugin

Refer [Manage Plugins for Your Multi-Device Hybrid App](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx) document for more detail on adding plugin

Comment: New link and new way to do this: http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/manage-plugins/

Answer (score 6):

On Visual Studio 2015, double click on **config.xml** file. Go to *Plugins* tab. Then you can choose between Cordova's core plugins or custom ones.